# is "shouldComponentUpdate" run on the server?

Tags: reactjs

Couldn't find anything in the docs about this, I need to do some browser manipulation on a parent state change without rerendering the child component. I could do this in "shouldComponentUpdate" and have it return false, but just wondering what implications this might have for rendering on the server side?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. `shouldComponentUpdate` should not modify anything. Cannot you listen to the parent state change somewhere else?

Comment: You're right, componentDidUpdate worked out well. I think this is acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `renderToString` on the server, then there won't be any implications, because `renderToString` does not call `shouldComponentUpdate` (*source: [Slide deck - slide #10](http://www.slideshare.net/larrymyers717/isomorphic-web-apps-with-react)*)

renderToString will call:

- getInitialState
- componentWillMount
- render

[Sample server render](https://github.com/larrymyers/react-isomorphic-demo/blob/master/index.js#L27) - [Sample client render](https://github.com/larrymyers/react-isomorphic-demo/blob/master/app/main.js#L13)

- Props to [Larry Myers](https://github.com/larrymyers) for the [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/larrymyers717/isomorphic-web-apps-with-react) and [code](https://github.com/larrymyers/react-isomorphic-demo).